# Angular Slider Collision Flickering

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, slider

I created an angular multiple slider directive and now I am adding features to it. One feature I am looking to implement is a collision detection with one slider bubble will float above another when sliding past one another. Here is a plunker with the full code example.  http://plnkr.co/edit/eg365UgK7ZNW1GZaTltQ?p=preview

The code to look at is on line 224 in the multislider.js

```
    //This is my code for adjusting a slider
    var delta = 25;
    var baseTop = -36;
    if (overlaps(bubbles[currentRef][0], bubbles[currentRef + 1][0])) {
      handles[currentRef].css({ top : pixelize(baseTop), height : pixelize(baseHeight + delta) });
      bubbles[currentRef].css({ top : pixelize(baseTop - delta)});
    } else {
      handles[currentRef].css({ top : '', height : ''});
      bubbles[currentRef].css({ top : ''});
    }
```

To recreate just slide the red handle over the green and will see the red bubble and handle and bubble does hover but flickers up and down. It should stay up and not flicker and then resume normal height after fully moving passed the green handle.

Why is it flickering? What am I missing to prevent this from happening.

Here is my github repo if you want to take a look and submit a PR there: https://github.com/enkodellc/angular-multi-slider

Comment: It's flickering because once the popup is lifted, then next time you move it, it won't collide so it will drop. You move it again, it collides, it gets moved up then it doesn't collide anymore ... and so on :)

Comment: Sirrocco,  Post that as an answer. So I can give you credit.

Comment: Don't worry about it, add you're answer with the code fix too and mark it. Have a good one !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sirrocco explained:

> It's flickering because once the popup is lifted, then next time you
>   move it, it won't collide so it will drop. You move it again, it
>   collides, it gets moved up then it doesn't collide anymore ... and so
>   on :)

I updated the code in the plunker to add the basic checks. Now I need to make it work with (n) sliders.

```
    //This is my code for adjusting a slider
    var delta = 25;
    var baseTop = -36;
    if (overlaps(bubbles[currentRef][0], bubbles[currentRef + 1][0])) {
      handles[currentRef].css({ top : pixelize(baseTop), height : pixelize(baseHeight + delta) });
      bubbles[currentRef].css({ top : pixelize(baseTop - delta)});
    } else {
      if (bubbles[currentRef][0].offsetLeft > (bubbles[currentRef+1][0].offsetLeft + bubbles[currentRef+1][0].offsetWidth)
          || ((bubbles[currentRef][0].offsetLeft + bubbles[currentRef][0].offsetWidth) < bubbles[currentRef+1][0].offsetLeft)) {
        handles[currentRef].css({ top : '', height : ''});
        bubbles[currentRef].css({ top : ''});
      }
    }
```